# How to remove unexpected parameter and attribute errors while importing data for sentiment analysis from twitter?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, sentiment-analysis, textblob

Q)
How to solve the following errors

1)Unexpected parameter: Lang

2)Unexpected parameter: tweet_node

3)line 25, in 
tweets = [tweet.full_text for tweet in tweet_cursor ]

AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'full_text'

CODE

```
import tweepy
import textblob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re


api_key = 'xxxxx'
api_key_secret = 'xxxxxxx'
access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

authenticator = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_key_secret)
authenticator.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api= tweepy.API (authenticator, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

crypto_currency= "Dogecoin"

search= f'#(crypto currency) -filter: retweets'

tweet_cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=search, Lang='en', `tweet_node='extended').items (100)`

tweets = [tweet.full_text for tweet in tweet_cursor ]

tweets_df = pd.DataFrame(tweets , columns = ['Tweets'])

for _, row in tweets_df.iterrows():
    row ['tweets'] = re.sub('https\S+','' , row['Tweets'])
    row['tweets'] = re.sub('#\S+', '', row['Tweets'])
    row['tweets'] = re.sub('@\S+', '', row['Tweets'])
    row['tweets'] = re.sub('\\n', '', row['Tweets'])

tweets_df['Polarity'] = tweets_df['Tweets'].map(lambda tweet:textblob.TextBlob(tweet).sentiment.polarity)
tweets_df['Result'] = tweets_df['Polarity'].map(lambda pol:'+' if pol > 0 else '-')

positive = tweets_df[tweets_df.Result == '+'].count()['Tweets']
negative = tweets_df[tweets_df.Result == '-'].count()['Tweets']

plt.bar([0,1], [positive,negative], label=['Positive', 'Negative'], color=['green', 'red'])
plt.legend

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. lang=en should be inside of the value of `search`.
2. tweet_node should be `tweet_mode`
3. The `full_text` will only exist if the `tweet_mode=extended` parameter is correct, and the Tweet is more than 140 characters in text length.

Comment: thanks ,can you please explain the 1 point again

Comment: `search= f'#(crypto currency) -filter:retweets lang:en'`, and remove the `Lang='en'` from the following line.

Comment: wait, also, you cannot use `#(crypto currency)` you mean #crypto_currency I guess

Comment: Can you please help in solving the following issues 1)I am getting the same output for all types of inputs pls suggest some way to solve this issue. 2)I am not able to extract tweets for a particular date since ,from  attributes not working.

Comment: You should mark this question as solved if the answer was helpful. I would suggest that you create a new question with specific information about what these new issues are. It is impossible to tell what might not be working without having more detail.

Comment: Ok Thanks have marked this question as helpful and created a new question. Link to the new question-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71192779/what-to-do-getting-same-output-for-all-keywords Hope you can help